# JavaScript menu dropdown problem in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 pop-up menus that basicaly open and close when clicked on. I wrote a little code that close any showing menu when the user click anywhere but 1 of the 2 menus. The code work perfecly fine in Chrome and Firefox but in IE, the menus only close when clicked on. I'm pretty new to Javascript so i am pretty sure that there is a better way to do it .
Here is my code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <!--     Main Header     -->

    <header id="header">
        <nav class="container">
            <img onclick="navFunction(this)" id="navMenuImg" src="img/menu.png">
            <img onclick="settingFunction(this)" id="navSettingImg" src="img/setting.png">
            <div id="navMenuSetting">
                <ul id="navMenu" class="navMenu">
                    <li><a class="navMenuLink" href="#">Videos</a></li>
                    <li><a class="navMenuLink" href="#">Pictures</a></li>
                    <li><a class="navMenuLink" href="#">Profiles</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul id="navSetting" class="navSetting">
                    <li><a class="navMenuLink" href="">Account</a></li>
                    <li><a class="navMenuLink" href="deconnection.php">Log out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <!--     Scripts     -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function navFunction() {
           document.getElementById("navMenu").classList.toggle("navMenuShow");
        }

        function settingFunction(){
            document.getElementById("navSetting").classList.toggle("navMenuShow");
        }

        document.onclick = function(e) {
            if (!e.target.matches('#navMenuImg') && !e.target.matches('#navSettingImg')) {
            var navMenu = document.getElementById("navMenu");
            var navSetting = document.getElementById("navSetting");
            navMenu.classList.remove('navMenuShow');
            navSetting.classList.remove('navMenuShow');
            }
        }
    </script>

    <!--     CSS     -->

    <style type="text/css">

    #navMenuImg{
        width: 55px;
        height: 35px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .navMenu{
        z-index: 1;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
        display: none;

    }

    #navSettingImg{
        float: right;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        margin-top: 12px;
        margin-right: 12px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .navSetting{
        position: relative;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin-top: 10px;
        border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
        display: none;

    }

    #navMenuSetting{
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: red;
    }

    .navMenuShow{
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        float: right;
    }
    </style>
</body>
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630980/js-file-works-in-chrome-and-firefox-but-not-ie has an answer.

Comment: Best suggestion: Open up browser's console and look for errors if there's any. It'll make your life pretty much easier

Comment: The error is : 
The object does not manage the property or the method "matches"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The js classList and target.matches is not supported in IE. I have listed the code that you can use instead:

```
    function navFunction() {
       document.getElementById("navMenu").className+=" navMenuShow";
    }

    function settingFunction(){
        document.getElementById("navSetting").className+=" navMenuShow";
    }

    document.onclick = function(event) {
        var matchesOne = event.target.matches ? event.target.matches('#navMenuImg') : event.target.msMatchesSelector('#navMenuImg');
        var matchesTwo = event.target.matches ? event.target.matches('#navSettingImg') : event.target.msMatchesSelector('#navSettingImg');
        if (!matchesOne&&!matchesTwo) {
        var navMenu = document.getElementById("navMenu");
        var navSetting = document.getElementById("navSetting");
        navMenu.className=navMenu.className.replace(/navMenuShow/g,"");
        navSetting.className=navSetting.className.replace(/navMenuShow/g,"");
        }
    }
```

The code is tested and is working 100% in IE and Chrome.