# Browser Compatability - Internet Explorer and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I know there's a few questions like this out there already but I can find no answer to this. I am having an issue with my site not running JS in IE (I'm using IE 11 for testing).

If I go to my site in IE it shows me the same as what it would be in another browser with JS disabled, except it does not show the error I have inside the `<noscript>` tag.

I went into the settings and enabled everything under the 'scripting' section and nothing changed. However when I changed it to prompt, it asked me 4 times if I wanted to allow scripts (I obviously clicked yes) and then it loaded my page but the JavaScript was still not working only now it showed me the contents of the `<noscript>` tag.

[image]

Is there anything I can do to fully allow JavaScript in IE or is there a way I can modify my JS to allow it to run in IE?

### Edit

There are no errors in the console and you can test this yourself with the following:

```
<script>
document.write('script');
</script>

<noscript>
noscript
</noscript>
```

Comment: You need to provide an [mcve] and look at the Console of the Developer Tools to see what errors are listed.

Comment: Have you used F12 tools to check if there's any error in console? Are you using some scripts not supported by IE11 such as ES6? Besides, there's also [a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630980/js-file-works-in-chrome-and-firefox-but-not-ie) you can refer to.

Comment: Does Javascript work in other browsers in your side?

Comment: Yeah the site works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera and Edge. Only IE is having an issue unless theres another browser I haven't tested

Comment: Actually just tested it in  Samsung Internet and it works fine there too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's some issue with your Internet Explorer. I could just give some suggestions due to this is not reproducible in my Internet Explorer. You can try the following methods:

- Make sure you have installed all the updates for Internet Explorer 11 from Windows Updates.
- Make sure you have enabled JavaScript in Windows. You can refer to [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135465/how-to-enable-javascript-in-windows) for detailed steps.
- Try to re-register jscript.dll file. To do so, follow the steps given below:

  1. Click on **Start**, type Command Prompt or **cmd** in the Search box.
  2. Right-click Command Prompt from the start search list and then click **Run as administrator**. (Note: If you are prompted for an administrator password or for a confirmation, type the password, or click Allow.)
  3. At the command prompt, type **regsvr32 jscript.dll**  and press **Enter**.
  4. Type **Exit** and press **Enter**.
- If the above methods not work, try to reinstall or repair Internet Explorer in Windows. You can check [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/318378/how-to-repair-or-reinstall-internet-explorer-in-windows) for detailed steps.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific, so with just the example above the issue comes with the prompt option in which case you will see both the script and noscript. I think the issue is with more complex JS like in your earlier comment, if the settings are set to enabled it will work for less complex JS

Comment: Yes, if you need further help with this issue, you can provide the specific javascript and html code so that we can have a better understanding of the issue.